# Hide Bootstrap 3 Modal & AngularJS redirect ($location.path)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 modal as a dialog confirmation in my AngularJS App. When i hide the modal and redirect the backdrop of the modal still remains.

```
$scope.delete = function () {   
  DataService.delete()
    .then(function () {
      $("#delete").modal("hide");
      $location.path("/");
    });
}
```

I have tried using the callback on hidden

```
$("#delete").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { 
  $location.path("/");
}
```

But the delay in this is a lot.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can also take a look at the angular directives for bootstrap made by the angular-ui team http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But the delay in this is a lot.

You are probably forgetting to call `$scope.$apply()`. Try changing it to the following (if the delay is the only problem) and the delay should be normal:

```
$("#delete").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $location.path("/");
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

All code that is called outside Angular (in this case from jQuery event) that interacts with Angular should call `$apply()`.