# AngularJs bootstrap model backdrop not closing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a strange problem when I dismiss my modal, the modal dialog goes away but the backdrop is staying. Looking what is going on I see that when the model is opened it ads a ng-model class o the body tag and adds two div's modal-render and modal-backdrop.

I created the ugly workaround below to solve it, but there must be a reason why it is not working as expected.

Any ideas where to look ?

```
        document.body.setAttribute("class", "ng-scope");
        var modalRender = document.body.lastChild;
        var modalBackdrop = modalRender.previousSibling;
        window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            modalBackdrop.style.zIndex = -1;
        }, 100);
        document.body.removeChild(modalRender);
```

Comment: Are you using angular 1.4.0? It's not supported by ui-bootstrap, which I assume is what you're using?

Comment: `angular.element(document.body).removeClass('modal-open')`

Comment: CORRECT it is 1.4, so which version does support it and what are the alternatives for 1.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

the link below has the solution, turn animation of on Modal to overcome the bug.

[$modalInstance dialog box closes, but screen remains grayed out and inaccessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653416/modalinstance-dialog-box-closes-but-screen-remains-grayed-out-and-inaccessible)