# Angular Bootstrap multiple modal backdrops

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using [this](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service) modal service to show a basic dialog in an Angular app.

The implementation is simple but there are two issues:

1. The dialog shows but the modal-backdrop class is repeated multiple times, rendering it completely black.

[image]

2. When closing the dialog, the form closes but the background remains, leaving the view useless. I'm sure this is related to 1.

I'm using Angular 1.4.9 with angular-ui-bootstrap 0.13.4 [2015-09-03]. I've found a couple of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191375/angular-bootstrap-modal-leaves-backdrop-open) showing incompatibilities between angular 1.4 and angular-ui-bootstrap but I've not managed to solve this.

Edit - view and controller code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-white" ng-click="procFileCtrl.viewErrors(file)"> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </button>

this.viewErrors = function(file) {
        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: 'modules/components/client/modal/modal-base.html',
            controller: 'FileController',
            controllerAs: 'fileCtrl',
            inputs: { 
                data: file 
            }
        }).then(function(modal) {
          modal.element.modal();
          modal.close.then(function(result) {
            this.message = result ? 'ok' : 'notok';
          });
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
```

modal-base.html

```
 <div class="modal inmodal in" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <!-- header here -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- body here -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You tried to use `scope.$apply()` ?

Comment: No, please could you explain?

Comment: Post the angular code in your question, when you open the modal and you close it

Comment: Check the edit, thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal ? It supports the latest angularjs and look exactly the same.